# CakePHP TimeHelper timestamp treated as object by phpunit

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I'm writing a unit test for a method that uses the CakePHP [TimeHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html)

```
public function testData()
{

    $timestamp = (string)Time::now()->i18nFormat('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
    // dump($timestamp); 
    // "2015-10-14 23:25:33"

    ...

    # data request should update the last_checkin field
    $screen = TableRegistry::get('Screens')->get(1);
    $this->assertEquals($timestamp, $screen->last_checkin);
}
```

I'm really confused why it works in the controller, and the return from `dump()` is correct. But the unit test *fails* with the following message:

```
1) App\Test\TestCase\Controller\ScreensControllerTest::testData
Failed asserting that Cake\I18n\Time Object &000000001a943b50000000016cb13674 (
    'date' => '2015-10-14 23:25:33.000000'
    'timezone_type' => 3
    'timezone' => 'UTC'
) matches expected '2015-10-14 23:25:33'.

/mysite/tests/TestCase/Controller/ScreensControllerTest.php:103
```

Why does`assertEquals()` think it's an object when `dump()` (and `save()` in my controller) thinks it's a string?

Is this a TimeHelper bug? A phpunit bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a TimeHelper bug? A phpunit bug? Or am I missing something?

Start with reading about [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring). Reading about the other magic methods won't hurt either by the way! There is fancy stuff you can do with them. Then [check the time class](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/source-class-Cake.I18n.Time.html#630-636):

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->i18nFormat();
}
```

assertEquals() sees it as what it really is - an object.

Assuming Table::save() here for your save() does a little more complexity in the background, however at the end of the process it ends up as datetime string in the DB if the field is of type datetime. This is because Cake is aware of the field type in the schema and casts the object to the right format.

I guess you mean [Debugger::dump()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/source-class-Cake.Error.Debugger.html#169-181) (be more specific!) - casts it to string for some reason I guess, honestly I'm to lazy to look the exact line and reason up right now. But I think you already understood what's going on.

Comment: Thanks as always for your eloquent answer. I understand the problem now, but I'm still confused why casting the TimeHelper object as a string didn't trigger the magic __toString(). The PHP docs don't discuss this.

Comment: Ok. So there's still a bit of a mystery. Using `$timestamp->__toString()` lets my test pass locally. But in circleCI it fails with:  `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function __toString() on string`